# Yandex Mapkit iOS : animate placemark

Tags: swift, yandex-maps

I want to animate `YMKPlacemarkMapObject` when tapped. I tried, but not working.

```
    func onMapObjectTap(with mapObject: YMKMapObject, point: YMKPoint) -> Bool {

        guard let placemark = mapObject as? YMKPlacemarkMapObject else { return false }

        let iconStyle: YMKIconStyle = YMKIconStyle()

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            iconStyle.scale = 2
            placemark.setIconStyleWith(iconStyle)
        }) { _ in
            iconStyle.scale = 1
            placemark.setIconStyleWith(iconStyle)
        }
    }
```

When using Google Maps, I can easily access markers `imageView` and transform it. For Yandex Maps I could not find a way to access `placemarks` `imageView`. Is there a way to access `imageView`?

Answer (score 0):

YMKPlacemarkMapObject does not support UIView animation, but you can animate any property of YMKPlacemarkMapObject manually using CADisplayLink for example.

I would like also suggest you to ask questions [here](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-ios-demo/issues). In this case it will be answered (by mapkit developers) faster.